# django forward relationship lookup

Tags: django, left-join, django-queryset

I know it's been answered more than couple of times, still from the docs and samples I cant figure out what's wrong with my code:
**MODEL:**

```
class BaseAbstractModel(models.Model):
  class Meta:
     abstract = True

  version = models.BigIntegerField(default = -1)
  update_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
  create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

  def save(self, *a, **kw):
    save_lock = LockFactory.get_lock((type(self), self.id,))
    with save_lock:
        self.version += 1
        super(BaseAbstractModel, self).save(*a, **kw)
  objects = BaseAbstractModelManager()

class SessionData(BaseAbstractModel):
    token = models.SlugField(max_length=20)

class SessionDataTransactions(BaseAbstractModel):
  session = models.ForeignKey(SessionData, related_name='transactions')
  submitted = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

im trying to carry out left join to do something like:

```
select main_sessiondata.id, 
main_sessiondata.token,  
main_sessiondatatransactions.submitted  
FROM main_sessiondata 
LEFT JOIN main_sessiondatatransactions ON   
main_sessiondata.id=main_sessiondatatransactions.session_id;
```

Have tried 'filter', 'select_related', 'prefetch_related', nothing works.

Is it possible to get all the values from LEFT(sessionData) regardless if matching items found on RIGHT(sessionDataTransactions)?

Any idea?

Comment: Could you clarify a bit what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes. Im trying to carry out LEFT JOIN to get all values from "main_sessiondata" regardless if they have matching records in right table ("main_sessiondatatransactions").

Comment: Am trying to do that nicely through Django ORM. Try to avoid raw sql

Answer (score 0):

Django doesn't do joins on reverse relationships, so the behaviour you describe is effectively the default. `SessionData.objects.all().prefetch_related('transactions')` will have the same result in two queries.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel, but I didn't quite understood, is that code you wrote provides the expected functionality?